# Is there a keyboard shortcut to close inline cell output in Atom in Hydrogen?

Tags: atom-editor, hydrogen

Now it seems that that the only option is to click the close button.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me: put cursor at the end of line preceding the output and just hit `Enter`.